# int to string conversion not working properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function that converts an integer into a string, basically what have I done is the following functions: when we get the numbers from the conversion they are reversed so I need a reverse function to make them in the right way. The `intostring` uses (I think? I got it from some website) the ascii table to convert the number into the string desired.

The problem is: when I enter the 2-digit number they are reversed the wrong way (I guess my reverse function doesn't work that well) and after a certain number of digit the conversion it's not any more accurate.

reverse function:

```
char reverse(char *stringa) {
    int len = strlen(stringa) - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        char tmp = stringa[i];
        stringa[i] = stringa[len - i];
        stringa[len - i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

intostring function:

```
void intostring(int num, char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        int rem = num % 10;
        str[i++] = (rem > 9)? (rem-10) + 'a' : rem + '0';
        num = num / 10;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    reverse(str);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that after modulo with 10 the remainder would be greater than `9`?

Comment: FYI this can be achieved with library function `sprintf`.

Comment: `strlen("ab")` is 2.  So `len == 1`.  But `1/2` is zero, so the inner loop iterates zero times.

Comment: Please don't "fix" your errors once a valid answer was given. This way your problem gets masked and the correct answer becomes irrelevant or even wrong. If you want to focus on another (part of) problem just add a new question.

Comment: Since the `reverse` is wrong, here's a [possibly] cleaner/simpler version: `char reverse(char *stringa) { int j = strlen(stringa) - 1;  for (int i = 0; i < j; i++, j--) { char tmp = stringa[i]; stringa[i] = stringa[j]; stringa[j] = tmp; } }`

Answer (score 3):

The condition `i<len/2` in the `reverse` function is wrong.

For example, if the string is 2-digit long, `len` will be `1` and `len/2` will be `0`. Therefore, no swap will occure while the two characters should be swapped.

the condition should be `i<=len/2` or `i<len-i`.

Answer (score 1):

The reverse function condition is worng.

If the integer in `32` then the string will be
`s[0] = '2', s[1] = '3', s[2] = '\0'` before string reversal.
so in reverse function the following swap operation has to be applied as

```
if number = 32 then len = 2
i = 0 then len - i - 1 = 1
so 0 and 1 will be swaped.
```

```
void reverse(char *stringa){
    int len = strlen(stringa);
    for(int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++){
        char tmp = stringa[i];
        stringa[i] = stringa[len - i - 1];
        stringa[len - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
void intostring(int num, char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(num == 0){
        str[i++] = '0';
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
    else if(num > 0){
        while(num != 0){
            int rem = num % 10;
            str[i++] = '0' + rem;
            num = num/10;
        }
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
    else{
        while(num != 0){
            int rem = num % 10;

            /*
                (-5/2) => -2
                -2 * 2 => -4
                so a%b => -1

                (5/-2) => -2
                -2 * -2 => 4
                so a%b => 1

            */

            rem = abs(rem); // as the rem value is negative
            str[i++] = '0' + rem;
            num = num/10;
        }
        str[i++] = '-';
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
    reverse(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @chqrlie for pointing out my mistake. I missed two cases `0` and  `negative` numbers. Updated the code with `0` and `negative` numbers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mine :) Your approach with `num *= -1;` does not work for `INT_MIN` because `num *= -1` would have undefined behavior because of signed arithmetic overflow.

Comment: Thanks, @chqrlie I have updated the condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /*
It works clearly . Checked.
*/
void  reverse(char source[],char destination[]) {
   int x,i;
   //start from last char
   i = i=(strlen(source)-1
   for (x=0;x<strlen(source);x++){
     //Insert char at i in source to x in destination
     destination[x]=source[i];
     destination[x]='\0';
     i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for an empty string: destination string would not have a null terminator.  Does not work if `source` and `destination` overlap, which is the OP's use case.  Inefficient as the compiler cannot determine that `strlen(source)` is constant, so `strlen()` is called once per iteration, for a quadradic time complexity. Setting the null terminator once per iteration is unnecessary too.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- the `reverse` function fails for an empty string. You should not subtract `1` from the length, but adjust the offset inside the loop.
- `reverse` is defined to return a `char` but does not return anything. Make it return a `char *` and return `stringa`.
- `intostring` produces an empty string for `num <= 0`. You should loop while `num > 9` and add the final digit after the loop.
- `intostring` converts the digit into a character for bases up to 36 (assuming ASCII). This is unnecessarily complex since the base is 10. Use a simpler conversion: `str[i++] = '0' + rem;`
- it may be useful for `intostring` to return a pointer to the destination array.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i - 1];
        str[len - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    return str;
}

char *intostring(int num, char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    if (num >= 0) {
        while (num > 9) {
            str[i++] = '0' + num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        str[i++] = '0' + num;
    } else {
        while (num < -9) {
            str[i++] = '0' - num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }
        str[i++] = '0' - num;
        str[i++] = '-';
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return reverse(str);
}
```

Here is an alternative approach for the `reverse` function using 2 index variables:

```
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *str) {
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = strlen(str);
    while (j --> i) {
        char c = str[j];
        str[j] = str[i];
        str[i++] = c;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the `negative` number case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reverse` function is wrong. You can make it correct (and readable) like below:

```
void reverse(char *stringa) {
    int i = 0; //Forwarding moving index
    int j = strlen(stringa) - 1; // the end index
    int tmp; // Edited to get the code compiled
    for (; i < j; i++, j--) {
        tmp        = stringa[i];
        stringa[i] = stringa[j];
        stringa[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have implementation defined behavior when storing `strlen(stringa) - 1` to an `int` variable if `stringa` is an empty string.

Comment: @chqrlie You're right, but all the major compilers (eg gcc, clang)  manage to cast UINT_MAX to  -1.

Comment: In this particular case, the conversion is `(size_t)0 - 1` to `int`, which is probably equivalent to `SIZE_MAX` converted to `int` and most architectures will produce `-1`, but there is another problem: what if the string is longer than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: @chqrlie I certainly missed that length being greater than INT_MAX case. However, I didn't intended it to be a generic solution for array reversing. In the context of this question, the length never exceeds 10 bytes. And after you comment, I fixed the compilation error for not declaring `tmp`